# Concatenate two or more different tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I have 3 tables namely;

**tableA**  with columns id, price, catalogue; 
  **tableB**  with columns id, sales, info, data; 
  **tabeC**  with columns id, name, desc

The **id** column relates all the 3 tables

How can I get a table like below in one MySQL statement?

```
    
        
            id
            price
            catalogue
            B
            C
        
        
            AESDR
            2000
            We are mayhem
            0
            1
        
        
            DRETH
            1400
            Let's go a fishing
            1
            0
```

The columns  **B**  and  **C**  above holds the value of either 0 or 1 based on if the item exist or not respectively in  **tableB**   and  **tableC**  tables

'Please note that the first three columns are from  **tableA**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT
    TableA.id, TableA.price, TableA.catalogue, 
    IF(TableB.id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS B,
    IF(TableC.id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS C
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.id
    LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableA.id = TableC.id
```

Comment: Thanks! But I used the same condition on both LEFT JOIN statement.

Answer (score 0):

Left join is your friend:

```
SELECT
  a.*
  if(b.id is null, 0, 1) as B,
  if(b.id is null, 0, 1) as C
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON b.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN tableC c ON c.id = a.id
```